# What’s the geographic distribution of different pronunciations of the word "experiment"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonology

**ᴛʟᴅʀ**: Which regions say the word ***experiment*** with its stressed syllable sounding like the word *spare*, and which regions say that word’s stressed syllable like the word *spear*?

#### PLEASE NOTE: This is *NOT* a survey question!

---

When it comes to pronouncing the word ***experiment***, there appear to be two dominant North American pronunciations that are rather distinct from one another.

1. Many people have the SQUARE vowel, as though the word *spare* were embedded in it. Discounting the rhotic, this appears to be the FACE vowel. 
   <sub>(But **sᴇᴇ ʙᴇʟᴏᴡ** if you don’t merge *merry–marry–Mary*.)</sub>
2. Some people have the NEAR vowel, as though the word *spear* were embedded. Discounting the rhotic, this appears to be the FLEECE vowel.

   (I’ve used [Wells lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English) here instead of the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA) in the hopes of making this question more accessible to a broader readership.)

Is there any geographic data on the distribution of these various different pronunciations?  If not, can we surmise or infer any?

Does it matter whether it’s a noun or a verb?

---

#### Burying Barrie’s berries

Listening more closely, those from the first set aren’t all quite the same: a minority have the DRESS vowel there, not the FACE vowel. These speakers do not have the *merry–marry–Mary* merger, so they say it with the stressed vowel of *berry*, which for them is different from the one in *Barrie* or *bury*.

For me, those are all the same. Because my own accent ignores the tense–lax distinction before a rhotic, I still perceive both of those subtypes as having the same phoneme, and it is only when listening carefully as one does when transcribing an unknown language that I can make out a FACE/DRESS distinction between some sets of speakers.

After [listening to a hundred samples](https://youglish.com/search/experiment/us), I’m now certain that there are a few speakers with the NURSE vowel there, as though the word *spur* were embedded. There might be some who shorten up FLEECE to the KIT vowel, but [due to tense–lax neutralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_vowels#Tense%E2%80%93lax_neutralization), I’m not very accomplished at distinguishing tense vowels like FACE or FLEECE from lax ones like DRESS or KIT before phonemic /r/. [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/):

> In many North American dialects, there are ten or eleven stressed monophthongs; only five or six vowel contrasts are possible before a following /r/ in the same syllable *(peer, pear, purr, par, pore, poor*).

It’s the first two (or three) of those that I’m talking about here.

### Research

An earlier version of this question narrowly transcribed the SQUARE version as [ɛksˈpʰeɻəmɛnt] and the NEAR version as [ɨgzˈbiːɻəmɪnt].  That's probably over-exaggerating differences of assimilatory voicing, aspiration, and reduction — aspects that are not the main point of my question. I’m just trying to divvy people up into the SQUARE group versus the NEAR group to see whether there are specific regional patterns in these two variations.

Dictionaries are a poor source for geographical data of finer granularity than grouping an entire country or even continent together, but here’s what they said:

- The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66530) has /ɛkˈspɛrɪmənt/ for both noun and verb.
- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experiment)
  has UK /ɪkˈsper.ɪ.mənt/ US /ɪkˈsper.ə.mənt/
- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/experiment)
  has UK /ɪkˈspɛrɪmənt/ (noun), /ɪkˈspɛrɪˌmɛnt/ (verb) and US /ɛkˈspɛrəmənt/,
  /ɪkˈspɛrəmənt/; also, & for v. usually, /ɛkˈspɛrəmɛnt/, /ɪkˈspɛrəmɛnt/; often,
  /ɛkˈspɪrəmɛnt/, /ɪkˈspɪrəmɛnt/.
- [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/experiment_2)
  has noun /ɪkˈsperɪmənt/, verb /ɪkˈsperɪˌment/.

What I’m looking for here is more finely-grained geographic grouping than just US-vs-UK the way those dictionaries provide.

### Any Geographical Data?

I’ve looked to see whether the usual suspects for such things have any geographical  descriptions of these two versions, preferably maps, but came up empty-handed.

I suspect that even in the absence of such maps, the distinct phonological processes at work in the two versions may be sufficiently characteristic of one or another region of North America that a good answer to the question of which regions say which of these could be formulated.

Comment: do you have any recording of the voiced version?

Comment: @DavidHaim Not right off hand, but I hear it from radio and TV  newscasters often enough lately that I should be able to pull one up eventually. Those speakers do not otherwise have a strong accent to me, which is why their pronunciation of this particular word stands out. I had initially thought it might be a Southern pronunciation, but in at least one case that I did try to track down, the newscaster appeared to be from the Northeast not from the South. My own accent is that of the Inland North, with occasional Canadian intrusions. :)

Comment: I went to youglish (https://youglish.com/search/experiment/us) hoping I'll find someone saying the voiced version, and the first 55 speakers said it unvoiced. maybe if you keep listening you might find more speakers and  maybe pinpoint their geographic location. although I'm not a native English speaker, I grew up on American English, and I have to say I've never heard it voiced. are you sure it wasn't the quality of the recording which screwed the audio and made it seem like a voiced combo?

Comment: *Exit* has a similar pronunciation divide; unlike *experiment*, I don't beleive the *g* version is purely American.

Comment: @tchrist I agree that these speakers say something like `(ɪ/ə)kspir(ɪ/ə)m(ɪ/ə)nt` except maybe one female speaker who actually says it with `ɛ`. my non-acedemic-non-native theory is that these people sort of merge the pronunciation of "experiment" and "experience" since they're very close both in pronunciation, writing and in meaning.

Comment: Is this maybe like the plural of house which has the variants /houziz/ vs /houziz/?

Comment: I reckon there's an intermediate that sounds like ik- or ig- spearmint. I've heard some with a tiny schwa between the spear and mint, and others with no trace whatsoever. The t sometimes disappears. Especially in the adjective ig-spearmin'l. I associate it with rural English in general. Some pronunciation examples here - narrator at 1:05, engineers at 20:45 and 22:40. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KncekYvqyWs.

Comment: @PhilSweet they all say it unvoiced.

Comment: @DavidHaim I’m tried to simplify the question to trim away the distractions of narrow phonetic descriptions and focus on the most readily apparent phonemic difference: whether one has "spare" or "spear" as the stressed syllable.

Comment: @PeterShor I did mention that some speakers have /ɛr/ not /er/ there, but that this was hard for me to distinguish because I've merged those. Nonetheless, in a recent sampling I made in pursuits of answers, all the UK speakers had /ɛr/ not /er/, even the Scot who of course had other interesting properties as well. The Scot clearly did not have the merger.

Comment: @sumelic Prescriptivist condemnation can be noteworthy in its own right, possibly even illuminating. Charles Harrington Elster is a Yale-educated New Yorker, and given anecdotal evidence showing a band of NEAR speakers stretching from Western Pennsylvania east through New Jersey (although there are other cases elsewhere in North America), it is not wholly shocking that he might condemn a pronunciation he may perceive as coming from from “the wrong side” of the tracks / river / town–gown / rural–urban divide.

Comment: does /e/ even exist in American English other than the /eɪ/ diphthong?

Comment: @DavidHaim Very much so. It's a monophthong for many of us before /r/, among other places. Notice the IPA transcriptions from the various dictionaries have no diphthong there.

Comment: @DavidHaim In your https://youglish.com/search/experiment/us link, there's a broader range of pronunciations in the first 100 clips than I had expected, more versions than I have represented above; some even have the NURSE vowel there. That said, I believe I hear the NEAR vowel showing up in speakers 25, 33, 35, 51, 56, 64, 67, 68, 77, 85, and 93. Some of those are more clearly the /ir/ version than others.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of this question.  "Experiment" has enough different and contrasting sounds in it that it is pronounced a hundred different ways.  Perhaps the only interesting point is that the variation is likely more dependent on economic status than simple regional/cultural factors.  Ie, pronunciation reflects, to some degree, the *respect* that the word is deemed as meriting.

Comment: @HotLicks The point is that I was until recently aware of only the SPARE version. Then I noticed a newscaster here and there with SPEAR, so asked for demographics because that seemed unusual to me. Since then, I've found that a few recordings have SPUR. It is interesting to see whether all this variation is regional, and if so, where. And sumeric has found deprecations of the SPEAR version dating back to 1947 even. The SPEAR version is heard in educated speakers, too, so it's not that.

Comment: "egg-spur-mint" is quite common, and rarely heard from educated mouths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my thoughts, guesses, and the small amount of evidence that I have gathered.

The pronunciation of *experiment* with the "merry" vowel (which is the same as the "square" vowel for speakers with the *merry-Mary* merger, and the same as the "nurse" vowel for speakers with the "[*ferry–furry* merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Merry%E2%80%93Murray_merger)") seems likely to be more widespread: as indicated in the original question, it's the main pronunciation given by dictionaries. It's also the pronunciation that would be "expected" based on theoretical considerations: a single vowel letter (other than <u>) in a stressed syllable followed by an unstressed, non-word-final syllable tends to correspond to a "short" vowel in pronunciation (this is sometimes called "Luick's Law"; it's also related to the phenomenon called "trisyllabic laxing", although that name is usually used to refer to some kind of process supposed to specifically affect  the pronunciation of certain kinds of derived words, and it seems a bit questionable to me to classify "experiment" as "derived" because even though we can identify an ending *-ment* and an initial element *experi-* that occur in other words, both would be bound morphemes; no word like **experi* occurs in English as a free base).

I suspect the pronunciation of *experiment* with the "near" vowel arose either due to influence of the spelling (the pronunciation of "e" in contexts like this tends to be rather unpredictable), the influence of the pronunciation of the related word *experience* (where the "near" vowel is regular because of the [occurence of unstressed "i" before another vowel in the next syllable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346984/why-is-salient-pronounced-with-a-long-a-sound)), or some combination of both.

The phonetic similarity of the vowels might also have contributed to the development and maintenance of the variation. (There are a number of other words of Greek or Latin origin spelled with "erV" (where "V" is any vowel letter) that show variation between these two vowels, such as *feral, [sclera](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sclera), [query](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321830/kweh-ree-vs-kwee-ree-which-is-the-more-common-pronunciation-of-query/321906#321906), inherent, coherent, adherent, hysteria*—although in these words the "near" vowel is actually preferred by prescriptivists because the vowel occurs in a stressed penultimate syllable, or before unstressed "i" followed by another vowel—and *(atmo)spheric(al),* for which most prescriptive sources seem to prefer the short vowel, but the long vowel of "near" seems to be common, probably in large part because of influence from the related noun *(atmo)sphere.*)

I think spelling pronunciations and analogical changes tend to have less clearly defined regional distributions than regular sound changes/mergers, so I am not sure if it would be possible to determine any geographical trends. Like you, I haven't found any source that addresses this question.

The use of the "near" vowel is denounced by Charles Harrington Elster, author of the prescriptive pronunciation guide *The Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations.* The relevant entry is available as part of the examples on PBS's website at "[What Speech Do We Like Best?](http://www.pbs.org/speak/speech/beastly/#pagetop)":

> **Experiment** ek-SPER-uh-mi̲nt or ek-SPAIR-uh-mi̲nt.  The first syllable is often, and acceptably, lightened to ik-.
>
> Do not say ek-SPEER-uh-mi̲nt.  Properly, there is no *spear* in *experiment.*

## Examples from the past

The variant with the "near" vowel doesn't seem to be particularly recent. It was warned against in an issue of the [San Bernardino *Daily Sun*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19470804.1.16) from Monday, August 4, 1947:

> There is no "spear" in experiment. The "e" in the second syllable should have the short (eh) sound as in error, errand. Be sure to say: **ek-SPEHR-i-m'nt.**
>
> [...] Two other words which *[sic]* the second syllable "e" is heard erroneously as "ee" are severity, as "suh-VEER-i-tee," and sincerity as "sin-SEER-i-tee." But, like the second syllable "e" of experiment the "e's" should be short (eh) as: **suh-VEHR-i-tee, sin-SEHR-i-tee.**

("Take my word for it", by Frank Colby)

There seems to be some evidence of this pronunciation from the 19th century in the form of the spelling "expeeriment" that seems to have been used intentionally by some authors in dialogue to indicate the pronunciation with the "near" vowel. The context suggests that the authors viewed it as a pronunciation that might be heard from "substandard" speakers.

Here are some examples I found using Google Books, going from most to least recent:

- 1898:

  > "Now, let's try an **expeeriment**!" said he, quite in the tone of a Franklin, or a scientific philosopher of modern days. "There's nawthin' like **expeerimental** conclusions. Jes' you turn your back toward the door, an' I'll turn the lock. There! Did you hear it, sir? Good! hardly noticed it at all, you say? Ah! I thought so; that'll do finely! Well, we'll try the hinges, now. How does it go, sir? Couldn't hear 'em at all, hey? Ha, ha! My **expeeriment**'s bean a *suck*cess. ..."

  (p. 511, [*The Latimers: a tale of the western insurrection of 1794*](https://archive.org/stream/thelatimers00mccorich#page/n517/mode/2up), by the American author Henry Christopher McCook)
- 1889:

  > "I guess Thorne's well-meanin' enough," said the other pacifically. "He's a scientific feller, and he's jist wantin' to **expeeriment** a bit."
  >
  > "Well, he kin **expeeriment** all he wants to with his iron and stuff, but I'd advise him to let flesh and blood alone."

  (p. 298, *[Alan Thorne](https://books.google.com/books?id=IFszAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA298&dq=%22expeeriment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAg_-ohtvYAhUMr4MKHcbtA7oQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22expeeriment%22&f=false),* by Martha Livingston Moodey)

Interestingly, some of the even earlier results for "expeeriment" on Google Books suggest that at one point, some authors associated this pronunciation with dialectal Scottish English, although I don't know if this was an accurate perception or if it was solely based on stereotypes or misconceptions about how Scottish speakers pronounced vowels. (And even if this pronunciation was in fact commonly heard from Scottish speakers in the past, I don't know if that's at all related to the use of the pronunciation with the "near" vowel by some present-day American English speakers).

I found a source ("[Overt and Covert Scots Features in Ulster Speech](http://www.libraryireland.com/gregg/scots-ulster-speech.php)", by G. Brendan Adams) that says that Scots may have the "feel" vowel in some contexts where English has the "pet" vowel, giving the examples "heid" = "head", "sweit" = "sweat", "frein" = "friend", "deid" = "dead" and "weel" = "well". But the words *head, sweat, friend, dead* all originally had long vowels, and *well* seems to have maybe had a long vowel in Old English, so the use of [i] in these words in Scots actually seems like a retention of vowels that English shortened rather than the result of any kind of Scottish [ɛ] > [i] change that didn't occur in English. I know very little about this however so this is just my rambling thoughts.

- 1875:

  > I'm far frae discooragin' ye frae tryin' the **expeeriment**.' An he baggit the ciller,--ha, ha, ha!"

  (p. 31, *[The Adventures of Mick Callighin, M.P.: A Story of Home Rule; And, The De Burghos](https://books.google.com/books?id=rCYmAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22expeeriment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2h9Swh9vYAhUCpYMKHf60D9s4ZBDoAQgvMAI#v=onepage&q=%22expeeriment%22&f=false),* by W. R. Ancketill)

  This book is set in Ireland, but the speaker here has a Scottish accent for some reason; on a previous page he says "Cawmill they ca' me in Coonty Doon ; we're a' Scoatch in thae pairts" (p. 26).
- 1828:

  > But a' the whilk time I ganged o'er the Atlantic, just for the sak of **expeeriment**, an' travel, and sic like--naething ither, tent ye--for I were weel aff at hame, in Embro', an' might ha'e hangit half the ceety

  (p. 4, "The Barber's Letter", *[Ps and Qs](https://books.google.com/books?id=3xoTAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22expeeriment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2h9Swh9vYAhUCpYMKHf60D9s4ZBDoAQhJMAc#v=onepage&q=%22expeeriment%22&f=false)*)

One thing I wondered was if we could look at rhymes to see evidence of how people pronounced it, but the short-e pronunciation seems to only have one rhyme, in "merriment" (used by the Victorian poet Robert Browning in the poem "[The Glove](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/glove-the/)": "Amid the Court's scoffing and merriment,—
 / As if from no pleasing experiment") and the long-e pronunciation only a possible rhyme for American English speakers in the obscure word "[diriment](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/diriment)" (for speakers with the *serious-Sirius* merger) or maybe a nonce-word "cheeriment" derived from "cheery".

## Examples from the present

A similar question was asked on the GameSpot Forums, in the thread [When did it become "Ex-peer-i-ment"?](https://www.gamespot.com/forums/offtopic-discussion-314159273/when-did-it-become-ex-peer-i-ment-32689812/) from 2002. But the participants there didn't seem to know of any regional patterns within the US either. The original poster said:

> I've been noticing this more and more, lately. I used to think it was a regional thing in the US, although I wasn't really clear what region it was.

In a later post, he says

> I've lived in Boulder, Colorado for most of my life but I'm originally from New York. My "accent" would be consistent with the Denver Metropolotan area, which as far as the US goes is one of the more "unaccented" examples of American English (or so I've been told).

Comment: I hadn't considered words like *query* or *coherent* that can have either of SQUARE or NEAR as well, just like *experiment*. That you've identified a bunch of other words with the same variation (but not veeriation) may well suggest that it is not just from the influence of *experience*. That said, I've not heard anyone say *severity* or *sincerity* with the NEAR vowel.

Comment: @tchrist: Actually, I think I myself vacillated a bit on "severity" in the past: I would definitely use SQUARE today, but I think that's at least in part because I "know" that it's the "correct" way to say it. "Seveerity" doesn't sound particularly improbable to me. But I agree that this doesn't seem to be a particularly widespread pronunciation, unlike "expeeriment", which is common enough  to have gotten into some dictionaries. I'd guess "variation" is safe at least in part because the spelling with "a" doesn't mesh well with a pronunciation with NEAR.

Comment: @tchrist: Another thing that may or may not be relevant is that the first vowel of "variation" only has secondary stress. John Walker’s entry (1791) for "[variation](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n542/mode/2up/search/variation)" interestingly says that "Mr. Sheridan has given this a the short sound of the Italian a" (although Walker doesn't agree with this transcription, as he views it as irregular)

Comment: why don't you use IPA? describing the vowels by the words containing them is pain

Comment: @DavidHaim: IPA isn't very precise in general, and IPA for English vowels specifically is a pain because the "pluricentric" nature of standard English and the long and widespread tradition of transcription means that there are a lot of different ways to transcribe things, and some people get a bit dogmatic about their way being the best. Depending on different things, the vowel in "square" could be transcribed variously as /ɛː/, /ɛ/, /eə/, /ɛə/, /e/, /eː/, or any of these with a rhotic hook. The vowel in "near" could be transcribed as /ɪː/, /ɪ/, /ɪə/, /i/...

Comment: @DavidHaim: ...and the vowel of "dress" can be transcribed as /e/ or /ɛ/. Using only a single one of these transcription variants would I think give my answer a sense of false precision, while using all of them would be a pain. You can read about these kinds of variations in phonetics, or just in transcription, in any source that gives a somewhat comprehensive coverage of English vowel phonology, but that's not really what this question is about, so I didn't want to get into that here.

Comment: Amazing.  It's always been "expeeriment" for me!

Answer (score 5):

Some data from major pronunciation dictionaries:

> **LPD-3** (Wells 2008):

noun (BrE): ɪk ˈsper ɪ mənt (the main variant); ek-, ək-, -ə- (alternative variants)

verb (BrE): ɪk ˈsper ɪ ment (the main variant); ek-, ək-, -ə- (alternative variants)

noun (US): -ˈspɪr-

verb (US): -ˈspɪr-

> **CEPD-18** (Roach, Setter & Esling 2011):

noun: ɪkˈsper.ɪ.mənt, ek-, ˈ-ə-

verb: ɪkˈsper.ɪ.ment, ek-, ˈ-ə-

> **The Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English** (Upton & Kretzschmar 2017):

[image]

Comment: It seems worthwhile to draw attention here to fact that your first two references are using /e/ to mean [ɛ]. Even though most people are used to seeing the /r/ phoneme not actually meaning a real [r], using /e/ for [ɛ] the way Wells has always done is not something everyone is aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I say:

> X - peri - ment

and I come from Manchester, UK.

Does this help?

Comment: No, not really, although I appreciate the attempt. In the first place, **I'm not trying to run a survey;** those don't work in our format. I'm trying to get a description of where each of several pronunciations are commonly said, described either in prose or on a map, or both. Second, you cannot use English letters to specify a pronunciation. For non-specialists, it is probably best to indicate which other words have the same rhyme for you, such as *pear* or *pair* or *payer* or *mare* or *mere*, or the same vowel as *nurse* or *mirror* or *nearer* or *berry*. Specialists might try IPA.